Manual SBOM SPDX Entries? (for undiscoverable packages)
I may be completely misunderstanding this as I am new to the generation of a Software Bill of Materials (SBOM). But I am presently using Microsoft's SBOM tool, and while it handles 99% of all related software packages/libraries used in our product, there is one (a big one), that is not identifiable by the tool (I assume because it's locally installed and not out on NPM, etc.), and therefore is not included in the generated manifest.
The package in question is Sencha's Ext JS 6.0.3.41 (and related packages):
##[warning]Some components or files were not detected due to parsing failures or connectivity issues.
##[warning]Please review the logs above for more detailed information.
##[warning]Components skipped for "Npm" detector:
##[warning]- "ux - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "soap - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "legacy - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "font-pictos - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "font-ext - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "font-awesome - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "core - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "charts - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "amf - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-windows - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-triton - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-neptune - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-mountainview - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-device-base - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-cupertino - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-blackberry - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-base - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "modern - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "touch-sizing - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-neutral - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-neptune-touch - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-gray - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-crisp-touch - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-crisp - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-classic-sandbox - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-classic - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "theme-aria - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "locale - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "classic - 6.0.3.41"
##[warning]- "ext - 6.0.3.41"

Since the tool can not auto-generate the appropriate entries, how should I go about creating them? I'm not sure how to generate a SPDXID value for them, though most of the other fields seem do-able. Are there any good resources on how to approach manual generation of SBOM entries in SPDX format in this sort of situation?
For example, using a version of Sencha Ext JS that is available on NPM, I get this:
{
  "name": "@sencha/ext",
  "SPDXID": "SPDXRef-Package-7290F3188D70A4EE3E6611F08999565DCD9F61F63596C5AFF2F0944C68263C17",
  "downloadLocation": "NOASSERTION",
  "filesAnalyzed": false,
  "licenseConcluded": "NOASSERTION",
  "licenseDeclared": "NOASSERTION",
  "copyrightText": "NOASSERTION",
  "versionInfo": "7.8.0",
  "externalRefs": [
    {
      "referenceCategory": "PACKAGE-MANAGER",
      "referenceType": "purl",
      "referenceLocator": "pkg:npm/@sencha/ext@7.8.0"
    }
  ],
  "supplier": "Organization: Sencha, Inc."
}

But where does 7290F3188D70A4EE3E6611F08999565DCD9F61F63596C5AFF2F0944C68263C17 come from? is it a GUID, a HASH, or something else? It's a bit unclear even after reviewing the SPDXID specs...

After a deep dive into the sbom_tool source code, it appears the hash is a SHA256 of "{package_name} {package_version} - {package_type}", so in this case it would be "@sencha/ext 7.8.0 - Npm" which results in 7290F3188D70A4EE3E6611F08999565DCD9F61F63596C5AFF2F0944C68263C17. Not t sure what to put in place of Npm for a local package though...

A little more digging and it turns out the Npm is a ComponentType, and in this case should be marked as Other, so the SHA256 would be generated off of @sencha/ext 6.0.3.41 - Other and result in AFC471DD0060B4C04DB0718C9C72CC58053680480B3A122A018F29E4B3F4BECA
